# Overfitting Checking in Cross-validated models for Hyperparameter Tuning and Model Selection Settings

Tags: cross-validation, model-selection, overfitting, hyperparameter

***Checking overfitting with cross-validation set metrics for hyperparameter tuning and model selection***

I have basically considered a set of models and pre-processing steps to tune the hyperparameters for model selection and hyperparameter tuning, using 75% of my data (the train set), with some validation sets (5 in total, so cross-validation of k = 5).

I selected the model and the hyperparameters that yielded the best metric in my favour, and fitted to the overall train data with that combination of hyperparameters. Now, after predicting on the test set and checking the metrics,  I would like to check overfitting, and one question arises:
[image]

- I know using the model to predict against the training set and comparing the metric is valid and straightforward.
- **But what about using the cross-validated model used for model selection and hyperparameter tuning metrics? Is there any impedement to compare the test set accuracy and that one, knowing it is a representation of having trained with all dataset points?**

Again, I have not found evidence against following that practice for overfitting checking, and in case there are opinions against, I would like to hear the underlying reasons for not doing so; or if it is even more adequate than a basic train - test set metrics comparison.